# What are all the ASP.Net MVC Action Results?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionresult

Is there a list of all the ASP.Net MVC action results and their uses?

I've been busily using ActionResult for almost everything but I know that's not correct and that I should be using more specific action results.

I've Googled this but cannot find a list.  We've just bought the Wrox book but it's more than a week away from delivery and I'd like to read up on this well before then.

Can you also roll your own and is that documented somewhere?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you open `System.Web.Mvc` using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), you will see that there are several derived types that inherit from the abstract class ActionResult.  They are:

```
System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult
System.Web.Mvc.EmptyResult
System.Web.Mvc.FileResult
    System.Web.Mvc.FileContentResult
    System.Web.Mvc.FilePathResult
    System.Web.Mvc.FileStreamResult
System.Web.Mvc.HttpUnauthorizedResult
System.Web.Mvc.JavaScriptResult
System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult
System.Web.Mvc.RedirectResult
System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult
System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase
    System.Web.Mvc.PartialViewResult
    System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult
```

Yes, you can roll your own by inheriting from the abstract class ActionResult.  You can study one or more of the ActionResults in the list above with Reflector to get a feel for how this would be done.

The source code is also available here:

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471

Comment: In the case of ASP.NET MVC, the source is available. It may be more *convenient* to use reflector, but there is extra value (comments etc) in the source.

Comment: Thanks Marc.  Shall take a look into that as well.  In the mean time I managed to create my own ActionResult that returned the word "Slappy".  So that was fun.  :)  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking this up for ASP.NET MVC 5, add [HttpStatusCodeResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult(v=vs.118).aspx) to the list.

Also it's worth to mention that the helper methods that return the corresponding action result, do not have the word "Result" at the end. For example to return a **HttpNotFoundResult**, you will write **return HttpNotFound("status description");**.

[ActionResult Class page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx) has the full list of result classes and the helper methods.